# Which oracle client of version 11g is required for cx_Oracle for python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, cx-oracle

[Instant Client Downloads for Linux x86-64 (64-bit)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)

From the above link which file should I download & set up, so that cx_Oracle in python3 will able to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Any of them should work but I would recommend the use of the 12.2 instant client. For cx_Oracle 6 all you require is the "basic" or "basic light" package. Make sure you pick the version that matches the "bits" of your Python. If you have 64-bit Python, pick a 64-bit instant client and if you have a 32-bit Python, pick a 32-bit instant client. If you aren't sure whether your Python is 64-bit or not you can use the file command, like this:

```
file `which python3.5`
```

The output will tell you whether the binary is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: For the record, the installation instructions are here: http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html